# CAB menu not working

Tags: android, android-tablayout, contextual-action-bar

I Have a tablayout, within which in each tab, i have listviews that use custom adapters. I have setup the listview to Multi MODAL and defined a cabmenu. I have used the same cabmenu in another activity having similar tabs and listviews. I dont understand what i am missing , the cab menu is not appearing on long press on the listview items. The only difference between the other activity and this one is, the other has an action bar. Below is the code where the cab menu isnt working.

```
public void showLists(){
    adapter=new CustomItemAdapter(getActivity(),listtype,fruititem,listid);
    lv=(ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fruits);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);


    lv.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            if (checked) {
                selection.add(fruititem.get(position));
                count++;
            } else {
                selection.remove(fruititem.get(position));
                count--;
            }
            TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contextual_title, null);
            tv.setText(count + " selected");
            mode.setCustomView(tv);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater menuinflater = new MenuInflater(getContext());
            menuinflater.inflate(R.menu.cabmenu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {


            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.deleteic) {
                for (ItemLists s : selection) {
                    dbHandler.deleteItem(s);

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mode.finish();
                showLists();
            }
                mode.finish();
            return true;
        }@Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            count = 0;
            selection.clear();
        }
    });





}
```

Comment: Maybe you answered yourself. If there is no `ActionBar` where do you want to show `CAB`?

Comment: @MisaghEmamverdi i know usually CAB overlaps or pushed down the action bar. But cant i have a CAB without an action bar ? I thought action bar is not mandatory.

Comment: No you cannot do that without action bar.